# how to modify an object using *& in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm getting myself confused over concepts involving pointers/references

If I had a function such as

```
void func(classA *&size) {
  //this is the part I don't understand what to do
}
```

if size had width and length, how would I change just length? (basically modify an object using *&)

Comment: `if (!size) size = new classA; size->length = 1;` for instance...

Comment: I'd recommend learning one concept at a time. Learn about *pointers* then learn about *references* or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `size` is a reference to the type `classA*`, it behaves as an alias for a pointer to a `classA` object, and can be used interchangeably with any other name for that object. Therefore, you would modify the object pointed to like so:

```
size->length = 3;
```

which is the same as what you would write if `size` had declared type `classA*` rather than `classA*&`.

Comment: Showing only an example where the reference doesn't matter is rather confusing!

Answer (score 0):

The function you describe takes a reference to a pointer as an argument.

This implies that the function intends to modify the pointer itself.

This code is already smelling bad. It is essentially sharing ownership of the pointed-to object with none of the protection offered by a smart pointer (unique_ptr, shared_ptr) reference, and no annotation to indicate that this pointer is an observer (see the documentation for the soon-to-be-standard observer_ptr).

You want to know what to do inside the function. Well it depends. The argument is set up to both communicate the address of an object to the function and receive the address of a (possibly different) object from the function.

If this is what you want, you probably already know what to do.

If all you want to do is pass a reference to an object, pass just a reference. If you want to pass a pointer to the object, pass just a pointer.

If you really do want to pass in a pointer and receive a possibly different pointer, I would suggest that the function should look more like this:

```
classA* func(classA* a); // returns either a or another classA
```

Even better might be this:

```
std::unique_ptr<classA> func(std::unique_ptr<classA> a);
```

Because now intent and semantics are concreted into the interface. The caller is now unable to misuse the function (barring deliberate self-harm).